# Cómo puedo utilizar jquery en local

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy programando una web en local para despues sacarla al 'mercado' pero resulta que jquery no funciona y la mayoría de las funciones de mi web están programadas en jquery, cómo hago para lograr que jquery me corra en el pc para poder crear mi web?

Comment: Estas usando el cdn de jquery? Da click derecho sobre tu pagina, anda a inspeccionar, console, te sale algun mensaje en rojo como por ejemplo no se reconoce $?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sólo tienes que:

1. Descargar cualquiera de los archivos de jQuery
2. Guardarlo en local
3. Agregarlo haciendo referencia a la ubicación local donde guardaste el archivo, preferiblemente en la cabecera del HTML, poniendo algo así:

   ```
     <script src="jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
   ```

Aquí se descargó el archivo minificado (ocupa menos espacio)  y está en una carpeta local llamada `jquery`. Le he dado el mismo nombre que tiene en el sitio de jQuery: `jquery-3.3.1`, así sabes qué versión tienes actualmente.

El contenido de ese archivo [lo puedes ver aquí](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js), como decía es una versión minificada, puedes optar por otras si quieres, todas tienen el funcionamiento básico de jQuery y algunas tienen particularidades añadidas.

La diferentes descargas de jQuery [las puedes encontrar aquí](https://code.jquery.com).